# Print unique lines, compare no more than N characters

Tags: bash, awk

With `uniq`, you can choose to compare only first `N` characters

```
$ cat foo.txt
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cat.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy mouse.

$ uniq -w 40 foo.txt
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Can the same effect be achieved using `awk`? I read
[this example](http://pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt)

```sh
awk '!a[$0]++'
```

but it compares the whole line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

awk has `substr()` function:

```
awk '!a[substr($0,1,40)]++'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cat.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy mouse."|awk '!a[substr($0,1,40)]++'
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: P.S. I just found the period after "dog" (in output) is missing. It was a copy/paste mistake. The dot is there in output after executing the awk command.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives using `FIELDWIDTHS` and `FPAT`:

```
awk '!a[$1]++' FIELDWIDTHS=40

awk '!a[$1]++' FPAT='.{40}'
```

Comment: You should probably state that both of these are gawk-only. And no, I didn't down-vote anyone.

Comment: How does a side note get more upvotes than a correct answer? 3 downvotes... these are perfectly valid alternatives to the `substr` solution.

Comment: Some people just love the down-vote button. Here, I'll give it an up-vote to take the edge off :-).